# shell problem: sending variable with multiple flags to a cmd

Tags: shell

In the following, the echo output is right, but the pgm is not receiving the flags correctly. Appreciate any insights.

```
script file:
flags="-umc -v -v "
r="";for d in `ls -d /tmp/passenger*`; do r="$r -x  $d"; done
flags="$flags $r"
echo $flags
/usr/sbin/tmpwatch "$flags" -x /tmp/.X11-unix -x /tmp/.XIM-unix \
    -x /tmp/.font-unix -x /tmp/.ICE-unix -x /tmp/.Test-unix 240 /tmp
```

Output of sh -x < script

```
sh -x < ./tmpwatch
+ flags='-umc -v -v '
+ r=
++ ls -d /tmp/passenger.15264
+ for d in '`ls -d /tmp/passenger*`'
+ r=' -x  /tmp/passenger.15264'
+ flags='-umc -v -v   -x  /tmp/passenger.15264'
+ echo -umc -v -v -x /tmp/passenger.15264
-umc -v -v -x /tmp/passenger.15264
+ /usr/sbin/tmpwatch '-umc -v -v   -x  /tmp/passenger.15264' \
   -x /tmp/.X11-unix -x /tmp/.XIM-unix -x /tmp/.font-unix \
   -x /tmp/.ICE-unix -x /tmp/.Test-unix 240 /tmp
/usr/sbin/tmpwatch: invalid option --
tmpwatch 2.9.7 - (c) 1997-2006 Red Hat, Inc. All rights reserved.
This program may be freely redistributed under the terms of the
GNU General Public License.
```

I think I need to feed $flags into the command in a different way...

Larry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the quotes around the variable if you want the words in that variable to be interpreted as separate arguments to the command.

Instead of this:

```
/usr/sbin/tmpwatch "$flags"
```

Use this:

```
/usr/sbin/tmpwatch $flags
```

---

Re your comments:

It makes no difference if the script is run from cron.  The script is interpreted by `sh` not cron.

Single-quotes in the shell *prevent* variable expansion.  Otherwise, variables do expand  -- whether they're within double-quotes or unquoted.  Try it:

```
$ food=banana
$ echo $food      # echoes banana
$ echo "$food"    # echoes banana
$ echo '$food'    # echoes $food literally
```

The other effect of quotes, whether single or double, is to make a string be passed to the command as a single word instead of multiple words separated by any whitespace that was in the expanded variable value.

Comment: Thanks Bill. The original script (from RedHat) had the quotes (before the passenger directories line was added). Anyhow, I thought the quotes were needed to trigger variable interpolation. Now I know better. Does it make any difference that the script is in /etc/cron.daily for use by crontab? Thanks again, Larry

Answer (score 1):

What Bill said. Here's a crazier to write this, by the way, if you're using bash:

```
#!/bin/bash    

# Store file names in an array variable. Same as (`ls -d /tmp/passenger*`),
# by the way, but the ls is unnecessary.
files=(/tmp/passenger*)

# Add each file name to $flags, adding -x in front of each.
# "/#/-x " means search for an empty string at the beginning of
# each array item, and replace it with "-x ". Effectively, that
# just prepends "-x " to each.
flags="-umc -v -v ${files[*]/#/-x }"

# No quotes around $flags, so each word is passed as a separate
# command-line argument to tmpwatch.
/usr/sbin/tmpwatch $flags -x /tmp/.X11-unix -x /tmp/.XIM-unix \
    -x /tmp/.font-unix -x /tmp/.ICE-unix -x /tmp/.Test-unix 240 /tmp
```

From the bash man page:

> `${parameter/pattern/string}`
>
> The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  `Parameter` is expanded and the longest match of `pattern` against  its  value is replaced with `string`.  If `pattern` begins with `/`, all matches of `pattern` are replaced with string.  Normally only the first match is replaced.  If `pattern` begins with `#`, it must match at the beginning of the expanded value of parameter.  If pattern  begins  with  `%`,  it  must match at the end of the expanded value of parameter.  If `string` is null, matches of `pattern` are deleted and the `/` following pattern may be omitted.  If parameter is `@` or `*`, the substitution operation is applied  to  each  positional  parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If `parameter` is an array variable subscripted with `@` or `*`, the substitution operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.

Comment: Thanks John. I'm modifying a RH-supplied system cron file so my assumption is /bin/sh is being used.

Comment: `sh` is really `bash` on Red Hat, but you can add `#!/bin/bash` at the top to pick your shell explicitly.

Comment: always? They don't have an alternative set up for that?